# Jackson JSR310 on Android

Tags: jackson

I'm building an Android app that loads a JSON file from private storage into a class.  The class is defined like this:

```
public class Foo {
  public Instant createdAt = Instant.now();
}
```

I have the following in my gradle.build:

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.2'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.2'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.2'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.13.2'
```

But when I try to serialize the class to JSON, I get:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8
> date/time type `java.time.Instant` not supported by default: add
> Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to
> enable handling

I've done this a zillion times before in Java (although that was not an Android project, and was compiled with Maven instead of Gradle), and I've never had an issue.  This is the first time I'm trying to incorporate Instant dates in an Android application with Jackson.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add:

```
.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
```

to the ObjectMapper, and then this started working.  I'm not sure why I had to do that for Gradle-based builds, when I never had to do it for Maven-based builds before.

Comment: I did the same in a Java server. Built with Gradle, but I wonder if that really makes the difference.